# Laravel : JWT Destroy all user created token

Tags: laravel, jwt

I am confused about `JWT destroy all user token`, In my project there is a `Manager Login and Manager team login`, If a `team member` which added by `manager` logged in and on other side if `manager` delete the team member from his lists `team member` cannot access anything from the app.So how can I do this ? How can I deleted `team member` all generated token ?

What i try :

```
if($request->email){
            $user = InvitedMembers::checkInUserTable($request->email);
            if(!empty($user)) {
                $user->status   = "Inactive";
                $user->save();
                $token = auth()->tokenById($user->id);
                auth()->invalidate($token);
                auth()->invalidate(true);
            }
   }
```

But it's not working.!!

Comment: How is `InvitedMembers::checkInUserTable($request->email)` different than `InvitedMembers::where('email','=',$request->email)->first()`? Can you confirm that the logic in the if statement is executed? Also, which jwt package are you using in your project?

Comment: @OluwafemiSule my mistake.editted.